# jQuery: making table cells content editable

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax

I am currently working on a small app engine project with python, jquery.

I have a simple table(people info for example) with a cell called "Edit" at the last column on each row, please refer to [this jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7yzE/14/)

If I click "Edit", I would like the other cells on this row are editable, and "Edit" turns to "OK";

I can then edit the cells of name, age, etc, if I click "OK", the updated content is submitted, the "OK" turns back to "Edit", and cells become normal(not editable) again.

Any idea how to implement this? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnLFS/

```
var editButton = $('#edit');
editButton.on('click', function(){
   $('textarea').removeAttr('readonly');
});​
```

Comment: By the way, the rest of your request is easy to accomplish. Just trigger an event when you click 'Ok' (or whatever), send your information to your server (in an ajax request) and set again the attribute to 'readonly'.

Comment: thanks Robert. can I use "toggle" instead of "onclick" in order to switch between "Edit" and "OK"(please ref to: http://jsfiddle.net/87Spr/1/)? any idea how to collect the updated content from these textareas with ajax?

Comment: You can use toggle by using $('#element').toggle(function(){ // change to edit }, function() { // change to OK }). You collect the updated content via $('#yourtextarea').val() and then use $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You need an inplace editor, like : http://www.yvoschaap.com/instantedit/
And a jquery one : http://jquery-in-place-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to implement the jEditable and datatables plugin for jQuery.  The datatables plugin website has an example illustrating this.

http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html

Answer (score 0):

Another decent solution, this has inline editing plus other features, filtering, etc.  http://www.apphp.com/php-datagrid/examples/sample_2_2_demo.php